# Why does Handlebars change the scope of the data we're passing to it?

Tags: javascript, scope, this, handlebars.js

Let's say I have the following "class" :

```
function Person( firstname, lastname ) {
   this.attributes = {};
   this.attributes.name = firstname + ' ' + lastname;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.attributes.name;
};
```

When I pass this object to the renderer

```
var myPerson = new Person( "Bob", "Robert" );

var template = Handlebars.compile( "<div>{{person.name}}</div>" );

var data = {person: myPerson, courseName: "LOG210"}

template( data );
```

The problem is that the **this** keyword in the function above is not scoped to the Person instance anymore. Instead it is scoped with the data that is passed to Handlebars.

For example, when handlebars calls **data.person.name()** function, the scope of the  **this** variable in **this.attributes.name** is the object data (**{person: myPerson, courseName: "LOG210"}**) not the myPerson object.

The cause seems to lie in handlebars-v1.3.0

```
// Template is only compiled on first use and cached after that point.
return function(context, options) {
  if (!compiled) {
    compiled = compileInput();
  }
  return compiled.call(this, context, options);
};
```

Why is the scope changed and is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Workaround: Declare your name method in the constructor and already bound: `this.name = function(){ return this.attributes.name }.bind(this);`

Comment: Interesting, but that does not allow prototype inheritance.

Comment: JavaScript prototype is not full classic object and have no inheritance support. So best way is to make different design instead of classic inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars don't assume, that you are passing prototype into it.

Handlebars work (and assume) that you are working with plain objects and helpers. Workaround is to use helper for function call instead of direct function call (Where handlebars changes the scope).

Helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ct', function(obj, fn) {
  return obj[fn]();
});
```

Template

```
var template = Handlebars.compile( "<div>{{ct person 'name'}}</div>" );
```

Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dp54p/

Comment: Looks like a great idea, but how would I include that expression in a {{#if}} {{/}} ?

Comment: Ah, need to use subexpressions. http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions